# Why does the Scala compiler error with "Synthetic tree contains nonsynthetic tree"?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scalatest

I have a following test

```
test("should create cached thread pool") {
    val globalContextMock: LogContextPropagatingEC = mock[LogContextPropagatingEC]
    val util = new PaymentExecutionContextImpl with ApplicationConfigTest2 {
        override protected lazy val globalExecutionContext = globalContextMock
    }
    val systemContext = util.systemExecutionContext
    assert(!systemContext.eq(globalContextMock), "system execution context should be a new instance, different form global mock")
}
```

which causes Scala compile the following error:

> RangePositions$ValidateException: Synthetic tree [1889] contains nonsynthetic tree [1874]

Anyone knows what causes the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling with -Yrangepos? If so, and you're using 2.10, it's a bug/issue with the compiler verifying trees that were (probably) modified by macros.

Comment: Yes and Yes. Hmm, I don't think though we have macros anywhere. Can you refer me to the relevant bug?

Comment: There's this one I filed. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8596. There's another one that isn't really a bug as such, but if you enable -Yrangepos then it will validate your trees. And if you insert a nonsynthetic tree into a synthetic, you get that error. And macros can do that, lots of third party libraries use macros now - casbah, scala logging etc.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line: `coverageHighlighting := false` into your sbt should fix it.
[Reference.](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) 
Basically it will turn off Highlighting functionality of `Scoverage`.